# Vuetify table will not render when it is placed inside another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I made a table component in my project as I have multiple tables that I want to all look the same.

I insert my table onto my page and everything is working fine.
On the table is a dialog which opens correctly but inside that dialog is another one of my table components and this does not render.
It will work if I change the name of the component and have two separate instances but that is not what I am trying to do.

How can I get my table working across all components? Using Vue CLI.

Table component:

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" :no-data-text="noDataText" :dark="dark">
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar :dark="dark" flat>
        <v-toolbar-title>{{ title }}</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical></v-divider>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn @click="dialog=true" color="success" class="mr-2">
          Load Default Frames
          <v-icon right>mdi-download</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn color="primary" class="mr-2">
          Create New Frame
          <v-icon right>mdi-image-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <Dialog v-model="dialog" />
        <!-- <Frame v-model="dialog" :editedFrame="editedFrame" :oldIndex="oldIndex" @close="close" />
        <DefaultFrames v-model="defaultFramesDialog" :selectable="true" :items="defaultFrames" />-->
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Dialog component:

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
    <v-card :dark="dark">
      <v-card-title>
        {{ name}}
        <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical></v-divider>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn icon @click="dialog = false">
          <!-- <v-icon @click="$emit('close')">mdi-close</v-icon> -->
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-title>
      <Table :is="child_component" :headers="frameHeaders" :items="defaultFrames" />
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn @click="log">Log</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Comment: Could you add a codesandbox or codepen so it's easier to debug the issue? I'm kinda lost where your <Table> in your dialog-component gets its properties :headers and :items from.

Answer (score 0):

Table.vue

```
<template>
  <v-btn @click.stop="emitOpenDialog">Open Dialog</v-btn>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      emitOpenDialog() {
        // I've use vueBus for emiting
        this.$bus.emit("open-dialog")
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Dialog.vue

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog"> ... </v-dialog>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
        dialog: false
    },
    created() {
        this.$bus.on("open-dialog", this.openDialog)
    },
    beforeUnmount() {
        this.$bus.off("open-dialog")
    },
    methods: {
        openDialog() {
            this.dialog = true
        }
    }
  }
```